# Software for high quality Animations

Tags: video, video-conferencing, animation

Hey I'm trying to make a promotion video for an app and was wondering how they do something like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wkhRnmLxKH4

I have no experience with animating, just with video cut (Sony Vegas, Premiere Pro). But it feels like requires some specific software. Would appreciate any advice on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks more like the job for a 3D modelling and animation suit, though some more advanced video editors may be able to do it to some extent.

There are many payed and free creation suites that may do that, most are commercial software, others open source.

- AutoDesk Maya
- AutoDesk 3D Studo Max
- Cinema 4D
- [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) is free and open source, we have a [community here for assitance](https://blender.stackexchange.com).

These aren't exactly entry level level software you can easily pick up in a short time, and all of them require some degree of investment, but all should be able to do what is illustrated.

Comment: Thank you very much, this sounds very promising. Im installing Blender right now...